Automatic Kerberos authentication of all users (SSO) via Active Directory in GLPI
I would like to make automatic login of all users with their credentials from Active Directory in GLPI. (And users must be authenticated as users, admins as admins, etc. in GLPI).
I have LAMP (Ubuntu Server 24.04, Apache v2.4.58, MariaDB v10.11.7, PHP v8.3.6; GLPI v10.0.15) and Windows Server 2022.
(GLPI is open source tool to manage Helpdesk and IT assets).
GLPI installed on Ubuntu Server and runs on a domain name like "mysubdomain.mycompany.tld". Windows Sever on "dc1.mycompany.tld".
I have a ".keytab" file (/etc/krb5.keytab) and when I checked this command:
kinit -5 -V -k -t /etc/krb5.keytab HTTP/mysubdomain.mycompany.tld@MYCOMPANY.TLD
I get: "Authenticated to Kreberos v5". So, it`s correct.
(On Windows Server I have an account with SPN: HTTP/mysubdomain.mycompany.tld)
(Apache uses the following module: auth_gssapi_module)
Here are the following my configs:

Kerberos config (krb5.conf) (/etc/krb5.conf)
sssd config (sssd.conf) (/etc/sssd/sssd.conf)
Samba config (smb.conf) (/etc/samba/smb.conf)
LDAP config (ldap.conf) (/etc/ldap/ldap.conf)
And my GLPI config (glpi.conf) (/etc/apache2/sites-available/glpi.conf)

-------/etc/krb5.conf----------------------------------------
[logging]
default = FILE:/var/log/krb5libs.log
kdc = FILE:/var/log/krb5kdc.log
admin_server = FILE:/var/log/kadmind.log

[libdefaults]
    udp_preference_limit = 0
    kdc_timesync = 1
    ccache_type = 4
    forwardable = true
    proxiable = true
    fcc-mit-ticketflags = true

    default_realm = mycompany.tld
    default_keytab_name = FILE:/etc/krb5.keytab
    ticket_lifetime = 24h
    dns_lookup_realm = false
    dns_lookup_kdc = false
    # AD in 2008+? Using AES
    default_tgs_enctypes = aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96 rc4-hmac des-cbc-crc des-cbc-md5
    default_tkt_enctypes = aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96 rc4-hmac des-cbc-crc des-cbc-md5
    permitted_enctypes = aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96 rc4-hmac des-cbc-crc des-cbc-md5

[realms]
    MYCOMPANY.TLD = {
        kdc = dc1.mycompany.tld:88
        master_kdc = dc1.mycompany.tld:88
        admin_server = dc1. mycompany.tld:88
        default_domain = mycompany.tld
    }

[domain_realm]
    .mycompany.tld = MYCOMPANY.TLD
    mycompany.tld = MYCOMPANY.TLD


-------/etc/sssd/sssd.conf----------------------------------------
[sssd]
domains = mycompany.tld
config_file_version = 2
services = nss, pam

[domain/mycompany.tld]
default_shell = /bin/bash
ad_server = dc1.mycompany.tld
krb5_store_password_if_offline = True
cache_credentials = True
krb5_realm = mycompany.tld
realmd_tags = manages-system joined-with-adcli
id_provider = ad
fallback_homedir = /home/%u@%d
ad_domain = mycompany.tld
use_fully_qualified_names = True
ldap_id_mapping = True
access_provider = ad


-------/etc/samba/smb.conf----------------------------------------
[global]
    workgroup           = MYCOMPANY
    realm               = MYCOMPANY.TLD
    security            = ADS
    kerberos method     = system keytab


-------/etc/ldap/ldap.conf----------------------------------------
REFERRALS off


-------/etc/apache2/sites-available/glpi.conf----------------------------------------
# Start of the VirtualHost configuration for port 80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mysubdomain.mycompany.tld
    # Specify the server's hostname
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/glpi/public
    # The directory where the website's files are located
    # Start of a Directory directive for the website's directory
    <Directory /var/www/html/glpi/public>


        AuthType                GSSAPI
        AuthName                "My domain"
        GssapiCredStore         keytab:/etc/krb5.keytab
        GssapiAcceptorName      HTTP
        GssapiBasicAuthMech krb5
        GssapiBasicAuth         Off
        GssapiNegotiateOnce     On
        GssapiSSLonly           Off
        GssapiLocalName         On

        # Use a cookie to keep the session, avoid reauthenticate user on each page
        # (facultative)
        GssapiUseSessions       On
        GssapiDelegCcacheDir    /run/apache2/clientcaches
        <IfModule mod_session.c>
            Session on
        </IfModule>
        <IfModule mod_session_cookie.c>
            SessionCookieName gssapi_session path=/;httponly;secure;
        </IfModule>

        Require valid-user


        Require all granted
        # Allow all access to this directory
        RewriteEngine On
        # Enable the Apache rewrite engine
        # Ensure authorization headers are passed to PHP.
        # Some Apache configurations may filter them and break usage of API, CalDAV, ...
        RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.+)$
        RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
        # Redirect all requests to GLPI router, unless the file exists.
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
    </Directory>
    # End of the Directory directive for /var/www/glpi/public
</VirtualHost>

# End of the VirtualHost configuration for port 80



Question: How do I make automatic (transparent; SSO) authentication in GLPI using credentials from Active Directory?
P.S. In advance, thank you very much for the useful information/code/how to do on this issue!

To be clear Active Directory is managed and run from the Windows side of things?

@David
Yes, Active Directory and domain (mycompany.tld) is managed by Windows Server 2022. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Since your issue is Windows it is off topic on this site.

@David  No, it`s not Windows issue, because "mysubdomain.mycompany.tld" (my subdomain) serves Ubuntu Server and I need to somehow configure Apache correctly...
